# Can we make the 'fiberchannel' tag a synonym of 'fibrechannel' (corrected spelling)?

Tags: support

The SAN technology's name is *Fibre Channel*. My tag reputation doesn't allow me to fix that misspelled tag.

Answer (score 2):

Done. Since it looks like you already migrated the tags, the old tag should get pruned for lack of use automatically.